# DDL statement of Creating a table through a java code is failing

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-spanner

Caused by: com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: DDL-statements are not allowed inside a read/write transaction.

Can somebody highlight the cloud spanner behaviour? I am unable to understand why this is not getting updated in the spanner

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a DDL statement (e.g create a table) inside a read/write transaction, only DML statements (query, update) are allowed.

To execute DDL statements with Java client, you can use SingleUseTransaction: https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner/blob/d617fb61eb0bba970c7cf4f43a4d50b54eb0f521/google-cloud-spanner/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spanner/connection/SingleUseTransaction.java#L250.